# Encode HDR content with ffmpeg directly into AV1

Tags: ffmpeg, hdr

I want to encode a short HDR clip from HEVC to AV1 while retaining all HDR informations. My goal is to use libsvtav1 as encoder.
What do I need to specify to retain HDR?

My current command looks like this, but I know that there's something missing:

```
ffmpeg -i input-hdr.mkv -vcodec libsvtav1 -rc 0 -qp 23 -preset 5 -acodec copy -scodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p10le output.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

-vcodec is deprecated, use -c:v, same about -acodec and -scodec. You need to tag the file as PQ function for it to be HDR (-color_trc smpte2084). Also you may wanna use WCG (-color_primaries bt2020 and if you use YCbCr use dervied from primaries matrix with -colorspace bt2020nc). Also you wanna use top-left chroma sample location. Also you may wanna set HDR10 metadata.